# How to stream custom camera from iOS app to a watchOS application?

Tags: ios, camera, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I've searched the web high & low to find a solution. WatchOS has the ability to use the stock camera app from the iPhone & stream in almost realtime to the stock watchOS camera app. How is this possible as I have a camera app that needs to display the camera view on my watchOS app.

From what I can tell, `WatchConnectivity.framework` is not fast enough to mimic real time streaming of images as the stock watchOS camera app. (I really doubt they are having the camera layer screen-shotted in multiple images & shown as a `WKInterfaceImage` on the watch.) Does anyone have any suggestions? Is apple using their own private API's to stream the stock iOS camera to watchOS? I'm very surprised no one has looked into this functionality in-depth.

I also find it frustrating that Apple allows their watch apps to open their iOS host apps, but won't let us developers do the same. (But this is for a different argument. :()

Thanks in advance for replies/suggestions. Anything helps.

Comment: What do you mean have the camera layer screen-shotted? If you take snapshot from AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer it will not be fast. You can grab frames from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and send them with Connectivity as images. You don't have to send every frame.

Comment: Hoi @stefos could you please be more specific? Thanks